# confused over casting between custom object and UIElement

Tags: c#, canvas, casting, uwp, children

my prog adds objects to a canvas of type grid, instances are called `vgridcargo`.
I can remove them by double tapping no problem.

However, they also populate a listview and would like to remove them from canvas from here also.

the issue I am having is how to a determine the index location of that specific `vgridcargo` (Grid) object in the canvas.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

If I cast it to a UIElement all items come back as -1

```
var objectToDelete = sender as UIElement;
        //string objID = objectToDelete.vCargoID;
        ShowMessage("element is at index" + _canvasref.Children.IndexOf(objectToDelete));
```

if I leave it as  I get

"Cannot Convert from VGridCargo to Windows.UI.XAML.UI.Element"

```
var objectToDelete = sender as VGridCargo;
        //string objID = objectToDelete.vCargoID;
        ShowMessage("element is at index" + _canvasref.Children.IndexOf(objectToDelete));



`vgridcargo`. Class



class VGridCargo
{

    private Grid cargo;
    private Canvas _canvasRef;
    private double vCargoWidth;
    private double vCargoHeight;
    private Brush vCargoColour;
    public bool vCargoHeavy;
    public string vCargoDG;
    public string vCargoID;
    public string vCargoImgPath;
    public double vTonnage;
    private bool isActive;
    // private static Dictionary<string,object> = new
    private TextBlock vText = new TextBlock();
    private Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint startPoint;
    private Point transOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    private RotateTransform cargoRotate = new RotateTransform

    {
        CenterX=0,
        CenterY=0,
        Angle=90,

    };



    /*public VGridCargo(Canvas canvas)
    {
        _canvasRef = canvas;
    }*/

   public VGridCargo(Canvas canvas, double inHeight, double inWidth, Brush inColor, bool inHLift, string inPath, string inID,double inTonnage)
    {
        _canvasRef = canvas;
        vCargoWidth = inWidth;
        vCargoHeight = inHeight;
        vCargoColour = inColor;
        vCargoHeavy = inHLift;
        //vCargoDG = inDG;
        vCargoImgPath = inPath;
        vCargoID = inID;
        vTonnage = inTonnage;
    }


    public void CreateCargo()

    {

        cargo = new Grid();
        //Properties
        cargo.Height = Ratioconvert(vCargoHeight);
        cargo.Width = Ratioconvert(vCargoWidth);
        cargo.Name = vCargoID;
        cargo.Children.Add(vText);
        vText.FontSize = 5;
        vText.Text= vCargoID;
        //** Look into sort out color's and brush's in program mixed api's?
        Color myColor = (vCargoColour as SolidColorBrush).Color;
        cargo.Background = new SolidColorBrush(myColor);

        cargo.CanDrag = true;
        //Handlers

        cargo.RightTapped += Cargo_RightTapped;
        cargo.PointerPressed += Cargo_PointerPressed;
        cargo.PointerMoved += Cargo_PointerMoved;
        cargo.PointerReleased += Cargo_PointerReleased;
        cargo.DoubleTapped += Cargo_DoubleTapped;
       // vText.PointerEntered += VText_PointerEntered;
        //vText.PointerExited += VText_PointerExited;
        Canvas.SetLeft(cargo, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(cargo, 0);
        _canvasRef.Children.Add(cargo);
        Stats.SetCargoCount();
        Stats.SetTonnageCount(vTonnage);



        if (vCargoHeavy)
        {
            Stats.SetHLCount();
        }

        if (!(vCargoDG==null))
        {
            Stats.SetDGCount();

        }
    }
```

code here

Comment: What is inheritance chain for VGridCargo type? It seems to be not a descendant from UIElement.

Comment: hey :), I added the `vgridcargo` class above. thanks :)

Comment: The cast is obviously failing when using 'as' , `objectToDelete` is always set to null.

Comment: Indeed, the cast if failed because VGridCargo is inherited from "object" class. It has nothing common with UIElement

Comment: Thanks , so type `Grid' doesn't inherit from UIElement? , excuse my lack if knowledge, but how did you know that?

Comment: You're not inheriting VGridCargo from Grid, instead your VGridCargo has no ancestor (i.e. inherited from simplest base class, "object")

Comment: ah ok, so should be class 'VGridCargo : Grid' and I will have to refactor some of the other code to suit.

Comment: It seems you're mixing presentation layer (Grid, UIElement etc) with model/viewmodel layers. Could you confirm you're familiar with MVVM approach (as it's a key thing of WPF, UWP and other modern frameworks)

Comment: no i'm not I'm just starting out, so go research MVVM 1st :) then, thanks for your patience.